# precedence of dircolors

Tags: bash

I have a file on 2 servers. The problem is that ls --color do not display them the same way.
My file is a binary executable (with +x) and also have a LinuxCapability (CAP_NET_RAW).
ls --color on the first server (Mageia 7.1) display with black on red background while the second server (Debian10) display with green over normal background (white).
I checked dircolors -p on both machines: CAPABILITY and EXEC have identical settings.

My first question: what is the precedence when a file has 2 (or more) of the attributes in dircolor list?
Second question: is there some option that would affect precedence?
Third one: what's the best way to diagnose why the two machines do not display the same way?
Thanks

Comment: have you checked `.bashrc`? Some commented, uncommented, line can affect the behavior

Comment: echo `$TERM` on both machines?

Comment: @andy-Dalton TERM is xterm-256colors for both

Comment: @mondo-cane Congrats! the .bashrc on the Debian server is not a genuine Debian file. We probably installed Debian without formatting the /home partition. I will close the question because the problem is probably caused by a system corruption.

Comment: But I would still like to know what's the precedence when 2 attributes are true. Is the color decided by first-found ou last-found?